# Kubernetes Rest API call equivalent to kubectl replace -f POD.yaml --force

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I am deploying plain pod yaml file. Attached is the snapshot of Pod.

My requirement is I want to update entire pod whenever its required.
This can be achieved by using kubectl replace command with force, it will take care of deleting and re-creating it.

Command is `kubectl replace -f pod.yaml --force`.

The RestAPI for replace is PUT (https://kubernetes-url/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/test-pod)
What query parameter I need to pass to achieve force replace through rest api similar to kubectl force replace.
[image]

Comment: Can you replace that screen shot with the actual YAML for your pod spec?  (You can't `kubectl apply -f` a PNG file.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `--force` internally it deletes the pod and create it again. `PUT` verb is not used in this case and there is no parameter for force in the REST API. You need to make two REST API call

1. First with `DELETE` verb to `https://kubernetes-url/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/test-pod`
2. Second with `POST` verb to `https://kubernetes-url/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/test-pod`

You can verify what REST API call is being made by running the command in verbose mode.

```
kubectl replace -f pod.yaml --force --v=8
```